# android how to parse json

Tags: android, json

```
    public void HelloWord {
       for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
             Log.d("Great");
       }
    }
```

The code above doesn't work why?
I try to get value name
Does anybody know where is the problem?

> org.json.JSONException: Value ...Content of link... at
>   org.json.JSON.typeMismatch at org.json.JSONArray.

Comment: maybe because it has nothing to do with parsing the JSON response?

Comment: It has nothing to do? I found code and use it, if i put there another json link, It works...

Comment: That's not the code that was here before :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are missing the way that JSON works.  Anything in `{}` is an Object, while `[]` designates an array.  So the root of the twitter feed is a JSONObject, NOT a JSONArray:

Try something more like this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(mStringBuilder.toString());
JSONObject trends = obj.getJSONObject("trends");
JSONArray today = trends.getJSONArray("2012-04-10");
for (int i = 0; i < today.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject tag = today.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = tag.getString("name");
  // do whatever with name
}
```

Much easier, and its clearer how it works.  JSONObjects are dictionaries, with a simple mapping between keys and values - each Object (`{}`) can contain either more objects, or arrays (`[]`) which can contain either simple integers or more objects

Comment: @user1106177 because I mistyped it - it was supposed to be `trends.getJSONArray()`, not `obj.getJSONArray()` - I've corrected it in my response

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the [GSON library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), as it is a fast and effective JSON parser. Once added to the project you will need to create classes to represent the data returned. You then can call a single function to create your objects for you:

```
gson.fromJson();
```

An exceptionally good article on the use of GSON can be found at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html - it even uses Twitter for the example.